# Production and Staging build are different

Tags: vue.js, webpack

My app has 3 enviornments, which changes the API base url:

• Production

• Staging

• Local

When building my app for production I use the `$ vue-cli-service build` which builds everything the way it should, perfect!

When building for staging I use `$ vue-cli-service build --mode staging` and this brings me some issues:

• My files have different compressing style from production;

• My files aren’t hashed containing the [name].[hash].[extension]

• My service-worker isn’t generated by registerServiceWorker at root.

How can I set my staging build to the exact same build that I use in production?

[image]

My webpack config

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require('webpack-assets-manifest');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["vue-style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.csv$/,
        loader: 'csv-loader',
        options: {
          dynamicTyping: true,
          header: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(csv|xlsx|xls)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: `files/[name].[ext]`
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id]-[chunkhash].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackAssetsManifest({
      publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_FRONTEND_ROOT_URL,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "API_URL": process.env.VUE_APP_FRONTEND_ROOT_URL
    })
  ],
};
```

Comment: If you want staging to be exactly the same as production, use the same command? Vue's probably doing some sort of `if(production) { minify and cache bust }` logic.

Comment: I need the environment to change, I have production API and Staging API (the testing version)

Comment: Use something like an .env file for that.

Comment: But I am using the .env for that, I have .env (for production),.env.staging (for staging) and .env.staging.local, thats the only point of using --mode staging

Comment: In my setup, it's one `.env`, with different contents on staging where appropriate. Not in version control. Again, it's likely Vue has various "if we're in production, do this step" built in to the CLI.

Comment: how do you change them based on the environment, and how would you define the environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution after 3 days of research, it's so simples it makes me crazy.

In my `.env.staging` file I just needed to rewrite `NODE_ENV` to production, that way I would have my API running as staging and my production config would run as normal.

```
NODE_ENV=production
```